# Manhwa in which the female lead reincarnated as a villainess girl in the world of a Boy's Love story

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

This manhwa is similar to *The Obsessive Male Leads Wants to Eat Me*, but has a different storyline.

The female character (FC) died in her real world, where she likes to read Boy's Love (BL) novels/manhwa, and reincarnated into her favourite story, becoming a blonde-haired villainess girl who bedevils the male lead (MC), who has dark-hair and red eyes. Her red-haired mother in the isekai world is the one who captures the MC and tortures him.

The FC is often ill, so she must be taken care of by the doctor, who has long white/blond-hair and wears circle-shape glasses. The MC's partner should be the blond/white-haired boy, who is the little brother of the FC's doctor. Since the FC realizes that her evil act may lead to her death (according to the real story), she then started to treat the MC nicely and is still going to be the cupid between the MC and his real partner (the doctor's brother).

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[Male Lead, I'll Respect Your Taste](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/male-lead-ill-respect-your-taste)***...?

> I was possessed by the devastating BL . Just before the historical event of the two main characters took place. Unfortunately, I can see how they both argue, but, I can’t do anything about it… “A moment! How is it that these two end up falling in love?” My main goal is to try to avoid being the villain murdered at the hands of the protagonist. That’s why I have to let the love of both of you be comfortable. But, for some reason, the strongest obsessive protagonist of all time has become a gentle sheep, who acts as if he wants to please me. “Alice… Do you think I’m pretty too?”
>
> [image: Front cover of the manhwa, "Male Lead, I'll Respect Your Taste."]

The main character wakes up as Alice Esteban, a blonde-haired princess in the world of a Boy's Love novel. Alice is initially bedridden with flu, and is tended to by Evan Elgar, a doctor with long white hair (tied in a ponytail) and spectacles.

The male lead in the story of the novel is Edwin, a boy with black hair and red eyes who's held prisoner and tortured by Alice's red-haired mother, Karina. His love interest in the story is Michael, a white-haired boy who's the younger brother of Evan.

Having read the novel, Alice knows the story ends in tragedy for Edwin and Michael, and that Edwin will kill her as an act of retribution, so she sets about trying to arrange a happy ending for the two boys, enabling her to survive as well.